# How to export the output of table() in R to Excel?

Tags: r, excel

```
gen_start <- which(colnames(westpac)=="RespID") 
gen_end <- which(colnames(westpac)=="sc_frequency")
for(i in gen_start:gen_end)
{
 print(colnames(westpac[i]))
 print(table(westpac[,i]))
}
```

Is is possible to export the tables in excel?? I have tried using count() function but it displays the variable name as "x" and it is not feasible to rename all the variables individually in the count() function.

So I want to fetch both the variable name and also the frequencies of various categories under it. I tried export table once but it just gave me the frequencies only.This is how I am trying to export the output in excel sheet or something similar to this will help :

```
[1] "QI1_15"
0    1 
977 393

[1] "QI1_16"
0     1 
1188  182
```

Can you guys suggest some ideas or is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(XLConnect)
gen_start <- which(colnames(westpac)=="RespID") 
gen_end <- which(colnames(westpac)=="sc_frequency")
for(i in gen_start:gen_end)
    {
       tmp <- data.frame(table(westpac[,i])
       names(tmp) <- colnames(westpac[i])
       writeWorksheetToFile(file=paste0("excel", i, ".xlsx"), data=tmp, sheet="sheet1")
    }
```

dplyr method:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- westpac %>% select(RespID:sc_frequency) %>% summarise_each(funs(n()))
writeWorksheetToFile(file="output.xlsx", data=dat, sheet="sheet1")
```

It would be way easier if you provide a reproducible data-set and desired output...

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your help. I've added the output as you said